# How to tell if the user changed the dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, postback, viewstate

I have a `DropDownList` and my method to populate it works as follows:

```
ddlStaff.Items.Clear();
ddlStaff.Items.AddRange(staff.Select(x => new ListItem(x.Name, x.Id.ToString())
  { Selected = (x == DefaultStaff) }).ToArray());
```

ddlStaff is in an `UpdatePanel`, and there's another `DropDownList` whose `SelectedIndexChanged` is an AsyncPostBackTrigger for the `UpdatePanel`. The event changes the scope, repopulates the `staff` List, then runs the above again.

Everything's working fine as is, but what I'd like to do is know if the user has changed ddlStaff so that I can basically do something like `{ Selected = (x == (UserSelectedStaff ?? DefaultStaff)) }`. Is there a built in way to do this? Or do I just need to remember what the last selected staff I sent out was (in the session or viewstate) and then compare it the actual selected staff when it comes back?

**Edit to clarify**: My intention is that I can send ddlStaff out populated with staff, and with the default staffmember already selected. If the user selects a staffmember, and then changes the higher-level scope dropdown, I'd like for the postback to not overwrite the user-chosen staffmember (unless of course that staffmember doesn't exist within the new scope). If the user hasn't changed the staffmember, however, I should overwrite it with the default for the new scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the response is sent out to the client there is no state on the server so I believe you cant really do a  (x == UserSelectedStaff); in your scenario with update panels I see no other way than some of a state mechanism, ViewState is probably on the bases that DefaultStaff object is fairly lightweight.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for helping confirm.

Answer (score 2):

make your dropdownlist "autopostback=True" ,and in your page load Event check

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      //now you know user made a change

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's because my question wasn't clear, but this doesn't seem like the right solution to me. This would be initiating a postback just to check if the dropdown changed. I'd still have to come up with the logic to store state of previous/current in the viewstate, so that I'd know what to do. Also, it would be much less efficient since it would be sending network traffic back and forth. Especially true if the dropdown changes from A to B then back to B again. In this case we've sent two postbacks for nothing. With the Ricky.G solution, I only need the state logic and nothing else.